# Call to ajax: None of "done", "fail" or "always" methods are run

Tags: jquery, ajax

(For anyone just starting to read this, this question is resolved -- see bottom)

I'm trying to understand what's going on in this call to ajax. This code iterates over a list of "binders" and fetches each from the server. (Right now there is only one binder on the server.)

What happens is this: There is about a 60 second lag where I can interact with the webpage, but no binders are displayed. Finally a binder shows up, but its image thumbnail is missing and I can't interact with it.

The output to the console from calls to "log" is:

> Binder: *the correct URL, which I must censor here*

and immediately after that,

> getAllBinders: Finished with item

Nothing else is printed, even after the binder is finally displayed. This tells me none of the methods "done", "fail" or "always" are being activated. I know that a binder is being displayed, so the code must not have crashed. (Right?)

Below is the code:

```
function getAllBinders() {
  
  var deferred = $.Deferred()

  _.each(binderPreviews, function(item, index) {

    console.log("Binder: "+ajaxPath+" "+item.url)

    $.ajax({
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      type: 'get',
      url: ajaxPath+item.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      crossDomain: true
    })

    .done(function( data, message, jqxhr ) {

      console.log("getAllBinders Success!");

      // Store the binder record with an index
      $.extend(data, { order: index })

      // Replace null properties with empty strings
      _.each(data, function(value, prop, obj) {
        if( value == null ) obj[ prop ] = ''
      })

      App.Binder.createRecord( data ).save()

      // Check if it's the last call so we can resolve the activity
      if( index == binderPreviews.length - 1 ) {
        deferred.resolve()
        console.log( ConferenceApp.Binder.records() )
      }

      console.log("getAllBinders Index: "+index+", Total: "+binderPreviews.length);
    })

    .fail(function(xhr, status, msg) {
      console.log("getAllBinders Failure: "+status+", "+msg);
      console.log("getAllBinders Index: "+index+", Total: "+binderPreviews.length);
    })

    .always(function() {
      console.log("getAllBinders: ajax.always");
    });

    console.log("getAllBinders: Finished with item");

  })
}
```

As an experiment, I added an impossible timeout to the ajax call (shown below). The output to my console was:

> Binder: *the correct URL, which I must censor here*
>
> getAllBinders: Finished with item
>
> getAllBinders Failure: timeout, timeout
>
> getAllBinders Index: 0, Total: 1
>
> getAllBinders: ajax.always

```
    $.ajax({
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      type: 'get',
      url: ajaxPath+item.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      crossDomain: true,
      timeout: 1 //Test -- this should be impossible
    })
```

EDIT: Never mind, I found the problem :/ There was a runtime error in the App.Binder.createRecord method that crashed the "done" method as soon as it ran (but not before, which is what confused me)

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: I explained in the post above the code. Only 2 lines are printed out

Comment: Are you using `$.ajaxSetup({async: false})` somewhere in the script?

Comment: Nope. It's definitely asynchronous, as "getAllBinders: Finished with item" prints out well before the ajax call is finished.

Comment: @NcAdams, possible to replicate on JSFiddle or something?

Comment: I don't think so... I actually think it's one of the methods in "done" that's tripping me up. So I'm wondering more generally what kinds of events could cause this code to stop executing (but also hoping somebody sees one of these events in the code)

Comment: FYI: `contentType: "application/json"` is the `Content-type` header sent to the server in the request.  It has nothing to do with the response's `Content-type`.  It's completely pointless here.